# output data into CSV file

Tags: php

I'd like to add a link for users to download data in .CSV format.

I can format data with PHP, but how do I make the file available to download (click and start downloading) instead of opening it in a browser?

Comment: if you search SO (StackOverflow) for "php force download" you'll find a gazillion answers for your question

Comment: Ah, they key is to know what to look for! Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force download a file using PHP [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php). You may need to add the appropriate header for your csv (if that's necessary) e.g.

```
header("Content-Type: text/csv");
```

Or to make it simple you can do something like:

```
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="desired_filename.csv"');
 header("Content-Type: text/csv");
 echo 'your formatted content';
```

It should bring a download dialog. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Set the header,

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
```

Comment: text/csv will be compressible. Do you have a reason for preferring application/octet-stream in this case?

Comment: @George, No. Just thought it being a "text/..." type would still encourage browsers to open the file.